# Checkbox - pass values

Tags: checkbox

I have a page with a checkbox that is populated from a sql. The table on the sql is setup as follows.

```
sopid, Type, DisplayOrder, Deleted.
1      test1  1            False
2      test2  2            False
```

What i want to do is if check test1 and test2 for example it outputs the sopID to a textbox in the following manor - 1,2 etc... Also if i untick one it removes it from the textbox as well.

Thanks

Comment: Is this Java? Or what platform??

Comment: It's an asp webpage written in c#

Answer (score 1):

The deleted column i guess is a boolean, so you could set an int in your code and pass the values in form of 1 and 0. 
You could do something like:

```
int i = 0;
if (checkBox1.Checked) 
{
   i = 1;
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar question where they have a maybe a more useful answer. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639708/retrieving-check-box-name-value-from-a-table-in-sql-database-into-ascx-file