# Retrieving check box name (value) from a table in SQL database into ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have tab names stored in a table named 'Importtabs' in my SQL database. Instead of hard coding the name of tabs i am importing i want to retrieve the names from the above mentioned table and set them as values for my checkbox list on the ascx side. Here is the hardcoded version that i was earlier using:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;"> 
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" BorderStyle="None" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
<asp:ListItem>All Temporary Differences</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>All Permanent Differences</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>All BS Only Differences</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>RTA Temp</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>RTA Perm</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>RTA Temp Other</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>RTA Perm Other</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>RTA Other Expense</asp:ListItem>
</div>
```

How can i do a similar thing as shown above but using the names ( 'All Temporary Differences', 'All Permanent Differences' etc ) from the 'Importtabs' table in my Database. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to retrieve data from a database, this code can be used to put that data into the CheckBoxList

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do not rebind the list if this is a postback; user input would be lost 
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }
    CheckBoxList1.DataSource = GetValues();
    CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
}

private string[] GetValues()
{
    // get data from database, with 'select <columnName> from Importtabs'
    // populate array
    // return values as a string[]
}
```

That will result in a lot of hits to your database, so you might want to run the GetValues() method once and then cache the results.

---

Links for [Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) and [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx)

Comment: i am not sure about how to retrieve data from a database. Can you give me an example code for the GetValues() method?

Comment: That's quite a large topic. Take a look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx to get started.

Comment: so i got it to bind. Thanks. But when i select the checkbox, the 'selected' option still remains false. Can you tell me how i can fix such an issue? maybe a snippet which tells me how i can see which checkboxes out of all are selected?

Comment: Do you have the IsPostBack check in there? If you don't do that check, the list will be re-bound on postback and user input will be lost.

Comment: You're welcome! I should have added a comment in the code about the IsPostBack check, so I'll update my answer.